# Why does my SPICE simulation have a different lambda value from my model files lambda value?

Tags: transistors, spice, multisim

I'm currently running a few labs here on my own since my university cannot do them in person and I have a SPICE model file in which the lambda value is set for a transistor. When I run a DC sweep on the transistor between the drain and the source and plot the graph and use it to calculate the lambda value I end up with a small discrepancy (1.5e-2 in the model file vs 1.31e-2 in the hand calculation from the simulations DC Sweep results) but I cannot for the life of me work out why? Is it to do with whatever way the simulation converges on the values or is it a case of because I only use a small area of the saturation region to calculate the value the result is off by a bit?

Any help would be appreciated!

**Schematic**
[image]

**Model**

```
.SUBCKT CD4007N 1 2 3
M 1 2 3 3 CD4007N
.MODEL CD4007N NMOS(L=5u    W=20u             
+VTO    = 1.77          Kp      = 2.169e-4      GAMMA   = 4.10  
+PHI    = 0.65          LAMBDA  = 1.5e-2        CBD     = 20e-12
+IS      = 1e-15         PB      = 0.87
+CBS    = 2e-14         CGDO    = 88e-8         CGBO    = 0
+CJ     = 2e-10         MJ      = 0.5           CJSW    = 1e-9
+MJSW   = 0.33          JS      = 1e-8          TOX     = 1.265e-10)
.ENDS CD4007N
```

Comment: It depends on many things you have not specified: the type of analysis (`.dc`, `.tran`), the number of points, the schematic, itself, how good is the model/subcircuit.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Apologies, I'm not really sure (beyond as I said it being a DC Sweep) what kind of analysis it is? The voltage went between 0 and 10 V and the step was 0.001. I'll add the schematic and model now.

Comment: @dbradley Can you consistently calculate `1.31e-2` even at different fixed values of \$V_{GS}\$ ?

Comment: @SteKulov Yes, at different V_GS values it is pretty consistently 1.31e-2

Comment: There is no guarantee that the LAMBDA parameter in the model file is used in exactly the same way as the lambda value you calculated by hand. In other words, there may not be any discrepancy.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Beyond lambda being the negative inverse of the early voltage what else could it be out of curiosity? I used r_o = 1/(Lambda * I_DS) to calculate lambda where r_o is the inverse of the slope in the saturation region.

Comment: If you haven't looked at the model equations for the MOSFET model you are using then no one can say. I don't think SPICE calculates r_o directly so the situation may be more complicated than you think.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson The issue is I'm using Multisim so I am not really sure beyond the model file specified above what the model equations they are using behind the scenes are. My lecturer has specified the standard 3 equations used in a MOSFET for each of the different regions but that seems to be it in terms of notes. I think what's really just confusing me is the fact that lambda is definitely specified in the Model file itself but it doesn't appear to be a hard value that's adhered to?

Comment: @dbradley In LTspice I can't saturate your transistor. With Vgs=20 I get a hint of a knee, veeery smooth, nothing fancy. Vgs=120 barely sees something resembling saturation. Are you sure about the model?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Interesting, it's definitely right as I copied it from the file I downloaded from the lecturer and it's working ok in NI Multisim? What happens when you set VGS to 5V and run a DC Sweep through VDS?

Comment: @dbradley Well, that was embarrassing. I had three sources in there, one inactive, and I was using its designator. Must be getting older than I thought. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I tried it myself using LTspice and am able to get the expected result.  It's possible your procedure is flawed, so I'll lay out how I typically do this measurement/calculation.

---

First, \$\lambda\$ (aka the "channel length modulation parameter") is calculated using the output characteristics (\$I_{D}\$ vs. \$V_{DS}\$) when the MOSFET is fully in saturation.  At this point the output curve forms a straight line.  To get \$\lambda\$, you must first extrapolate this line and find the \$V_{DS}\$-intercept.  For different \$V_{GS}\$, this \$V_{DS}\$-intercept point will be the same, so \$\lambda\$ will also be the same.  The following image [from this website](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/describe-channel-length-modulation-effect-define-parameter-chapter-3-problem-4rq-solution-9780073380643-exc) highlights this behavior:

[image]

You can use the equation for lines to get an easier expression to work with, which I'll do below.

$$
\begin{align*}
y = mx + b &\implies x\text{-intercept} = -\frac{b}{m} \\
&\implies -\frac{1}{\lambda} = -\frac{I_{D}\text{-intercept}}{\text{slope}} \\
&\implies \lambda = \frac{\text{slope}}{I_{D}\text{-intercept}} \\
\end{align*}
$$

I like to do one more simplification, which allows us to plug in values directly from the LTspice plots without having to explicitly calculate the \$I_{D}\$-intercept.  If we take a specific point on the line \$(V_{DS_1},I_{D_1})\$ we can rewrite as:

$$
\begin{align*}
&I_{D}\text{-intercept} = I_{D_1} - \text{slope} \cdot V_{DS_1} \\ \\
&\therefore \text{ } \lambda = \frac{\text{slope}}{I_{D_1} - \text{slope} \cdot V_{DS_1}}
\end{align*}
$$

---

With the above information, we can perform the simulation on the circuit in question.  I chose your same \$V_{GS}\$, but swept the \$V_{DS}\$ up through 20V because that's around where I was satisfied with "straightness" of the line.  When plotting \$I_{D}\$ vs. \$V_{DS}\$, I selected points at 20V and 19V to get the slope.

[image]

Using the slope and one of the points (I used the one on "Cursor 2"), we can solve the equation derived above:

$$
\lambda = \frac{\text{slope}}{I_{D_1} - \text{slope} \cdot V_{DS_1}} = \frac{(637.561 \times 10^{-6})}{(55.255 \times 10^{-3}) - [(637.561 \times 10^{-6}) \cdot 20]} = 15 \times 10^{-3}
$$