# Transistor values in LT Spice - Extraction

Tags: transistors, ltspice

In my integrated analog electronics course I've been given a transistor circuit and some operating point values: -

[image]

I'm asked to find things like the output resistance \$r_{out} \$ and the small signal gain \$A_v \$ for the circuit. I can do these things by hand, although somewhat laboriously. For example, I believe I found that \$r_{out} = (r_{ds3}g_{m3}r_{ds4}) ||(r_{ds2}g_{m2}r_{ds1}) \$, but I have no way to double check this.

**My question is**, is there a way to replicate the circuit in a simulator (like LTSpice) to make a sanity test with the current information given? Can we somehow extract information about \$\mu_nC_{ox} \$ and \$\frac{W}{L} \$ and \$\lambda \$ that we can use in LTSpice? Or perhaps there is another way?

Comment: 1) Realize that the MOSFET models used by simulators are quite complex, (that came up in a recent question, read: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/599004/mosfet-spice-model#comment1574246_599004 ) so extracting W/L etc will not give you valid results easily. But you don't need W/L etc. What matters for smal signal? The gm, gds etc. and those are given.

Comment: 2) Yes, you can put the circuit in a simulator and provided you would be using the models and model parameters (transistor properties, that will be a challenge since W/L is unknown) you can then determine the output impedance....

Comment: What I do: DC-bias the circuit as required. Place a current source between output and ground. Its DC current must be zero (to not disturb the DC solution) and its AC current I set to 1 A. Yes 1 A as we're going to do an AC analysis and that linearizes everything (so 1 A is OK), same as in a small signal model. Then sweep over frequency and plot AC voltage at output, that's the impedance. If at a certain frequency you get 1 M volt (yes 1 Mega volt, again, this is linearized!) that means the impedance is 1 M ohm.

Comment: [See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/533654/95619) for example. But you're better off asking your teacher how he got those results, so you can replicate and study them home.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie But how would you bias the circuit if you don't have the transistor values in the first place? Would you just a generic transistor model?

Comment: *But how would you bias the circuit if you don't have the transistor values in the first place?* In your exercise you do not have the design details (like W/L). But when I design a circuit, **I do**, because I'm designing the circuit ;-) . For the voltages I can just use a voltage source. For the currents I can use a current source or current source + current mirror.

Comment: Oh, and one small comment regarding the title of your question: You mention "Extraction", in the analog IC design world, extraction has a different meaning. When we have the design in schematic, the layout is made. On that layout we can then do **parasitic extraction** which derives the resitances and capacitances of the metal wires connecting the components. This is just an informational comment, you can leave the title as-is as it is clear what you mean from the text.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Oh okay, thanks for letting me know :). And yeah, I guess I have to stick with the old pencil paper methods for these types of problems.

Comment: I think it is possible to reverse engineer the w/l ratios and simulate this circuit (assuming you know you are using the same model file as your professor). All the DC bias points are given. You could, for example, take gds~(lambda X Id) / L, for some W and L. to get lambda, and work your way up to kn' etc (using 1st order model approximation). But, you might not get exact values.  I think the rout eq. you show is very well known and you would be safe following the literature and texts for that and common measurements like gain (gm_in*rout).

Comment: Another approach is bias all the dc points and work on sweeping w and l values to match the operating points (esp. current at first). It could be tricky, as he possibly might have used different l and w for every device (but doubtful, more likely w/l p is some scaled version of w/l n - scaled by intrinsic mobility ratios). If you provide the model file, I can try to attempt this. It's a good exercise in design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how to approach verifying an example through LTspice.
Note that I just grabbed an arbitrary short channel model file, but the principles are the same.

[image]

1. You know all of the DC bias points from the data given. You can start building the bottom nmos sizes from using the dc bias stimulus and sweeping the w values to get the dc currents to match close to the ones given. I chose arbitrary l=.5u and swept w.
2. Once you size the bottom nmos devices, you can add the pmos devices and sweep w to get approximately vdd/2 at vout (as your given data shows).
3. You can calculate your small signal parameters, like \$rout\$ as you showed in your example.
4. You can then check things like \$rout\$ against a test bench (as explained in the comments by Bimpelrekkie). Or take it one step further and check DC gain (\$gm_{in}*rout\$ at f=0).
5. Compare your calculation to the measurement expected. Here I used \$Av_{OL}=gm_{4}rout\$ to get 461. I used an ac sweep to verify the gain. The error is within 3%.
6. There may be mismatches between sim and calculation. But here, we are using very simple first order models to calculate and short channel models to simulate. So it can be expected to have some differences.
7. What is important is not that you match the example you showed exactly. But that you know how to setup some tests in LTspice and calculate your expected parameters against your simulated test bench.

Comment: Why would you need to run simulations to get the transistor parameters if you had the **model file**? I think the whole point of the OP's question is that they had only the information for the single bias point.

Comment: @Elliot. He does not have the device sizes and asked if there is some way to simulate and extract the schematic values and measurements without having any knowledge of them (to verify calcs). The model file will not give you that information nor can you emulate a test bench in LTspice for that schematic without them. The method I showed can closely reverse engineer them. Once you have the sizes, you can set up test benches in ltspice as a sanity check to verify things like rout, and gain against the values you calculated indirectly through a limited .op file output. This is a way to do that.

Comment: OK, why would you need to run simulations to get the device sizes if you have the **SPICE netlist**? W and L are necessary to run SPICE with every MOS model file that I have ever used.

Comment: And the OP didn't ask how to get the answers **given access to the SPICE models**. They wanted to know how to get the answers given **only** the information shown in the question.

Comment: You really need to go back and re read the question. I don't think you understand it. "My question is, is there a way to replicate the circuit in a simulator (like LTSpice) to make a sanity test with the current information given?" Obviously, if the SPICE netlist with device sizes was included, there would be no need for that question or my answer. Where is this SPICE netlist you insist that he has? He asked how can he simulate it in LTspice given ONLY the information he had, which is an .op output file NOT a SPICE netlist.